# AutoMapper exception

Tags: c#, automapper

When I run the line of code Mapper.Map(Account, User); I get a "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" exception.  I'd also like to note that the line Mapper.Map(Account); does not throw an exception and returns the expected results. What I'm trying to do is move the values from Account to User without creating a new instance of User. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
public class AccountUpdate
{
    [Email]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Your name must be between 3 and 25 characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Roles { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}


Mapper.CreateMap<AccountUpdate, User>().ForMember(d => d.Roles, s => s.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not mapping all members of the destination class.

Call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` for detailed information about the problem:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
==============================================================
AccountUpdate -> User (Destination member list)
ConsoleApplication1.AccountUpdate -> ConsoleApplication1.User (Destination member list)
--------------------------------------------------------------
UserId
Password
Salt
CreatedOn
LastLogin
```

To solve this, explicitly ignore the unmapped members.

---

I just tested this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountUpdate, User>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Roles, s => s.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.UserId, s => s.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.Password, s => s.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.Salt, s => s.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.CreatedOn, s => s.Ignore())
        .ForMember(d => d.LastLogin, s => s.Ignore());

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var update = new AccountUpdate
{
    Email = "foo@bar.com",
    Name = "The name",
    Roles = "not important"
};

var user = Mapper.Map<AccountUpdate, User>(update);

Trace.Assert(user.Email == update.Email);
Trace.Assert(user.Name == update.Name);
```

---

This works, too:

```
var user = new User();
Mapper.Map(update, user);

Trace.Assert(user.Email == update.Email);
Trace.Assert(user.Name == update.Name);
```

Comment: I tried explicitly ignoring the unmapped members but when I call Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); I get the same thing listed above. My config now looks like this:               Mapper.CreateMap<AccountUpdate, User>().ForMember(d => d.Roles, s => s.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.UserId, s => s.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.Password, s => s.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.Salt, s => s.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedOn, s => s.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d => d.LastLogin, s => s.Ignore());

Comment: Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); is no longer throwing an exception and a call like var user = Mapper.Map<AccountUpdate, User>(update); will work but when I call var b = Mapper.Map<AccountUpdate, User>(Account, User); I'm still getting an exception.

Comment: Can you please post the full exception message? Are you sure the objects you pass to `Map` are of the type you've defined the mapping for? And not proxies, collections etc?

Comment: The object is a proxy since it is being generated by a DbContext.

Comment: i'm going to throw it out there, I hate autocrapper

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue logged on the project that outlines a potential solution, which is to use the source object as the mapping, not the destination.  The [original thread is here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1386), and the relevant code sample was:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>(MemberList.Source)
```

There is also a more generic extension method someone wrote in the linked issue, that also might help save time.